# React router with http-server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, httpserver

we use `react-roucter-dom` with `http-server` , when user loads main page and click navigation links , new pages will loaded perfectly , but when user refresh page in that route , it returns 404 .
It means HTML5 `pushState` is not working with `http-server`.

example :

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
</Router>
```

If user go to `/about` page and refresh it , 404 error will happen

Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use this when you run http-server :

```
http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080? ./build
```

It is redirecting any error requests it can't handle to index.html where your react-router configuration resides. If all requests come to this page, then the react-router takes care of routing internally.

By the way, I've built a small script in package.json - scripts , to call all this and serve the build folder like this :

```
scripts: {
           ...
           "serveprod": "npm run build && http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080? ./build"
           ...
       }
```

And just run :

```
 npm run serveprod
```

Comment: Tip:: For create-react-app, you have to either specify the `homepage` in `package.json` or set the `.env` variable accordingly: `PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:8080 yarn build && http-server --proxy http://localhost:8080? ./build`

Comment: What's the motivation of the trailing question mark? I had to remove it to make it work...

Comment: @bluenote10 the command cames from `http-server` documentation, https://github.com/http-party/http-server#catch-all-redirect

Comment: Thanks. What is the question mark at the end (of the URL)?

Comment: How to make this work with proxying API calls to remote backend?

Comment: @Raviteja VK Should I use `http://localhost:8080?` in production as well? or replace it with the server domain?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in my React + Webpack project. I've found the solution on [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#other-solutions).

You have to:

1. in React project run `npm i --save express` ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express))
2. create new file in project root directory (f.e. `server.js`)
3. write there http server code, that in every endpoint returns `index.html`:

```js
// libs
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
// create server
const app = express();

const PORT = 3000;
const BUILD_FOLDER = "public";

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, BUILD_FOLDER)));

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, BUILD_FOLDER, "index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

4. Start server with `node server.js` (live console) or `node server.js 1>server.log 2>server-error.log &` (background process that you can find later with `ps uax | grep node`)

I know this post is old but maybe somebody will find that useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your error happens since your application is a Single Page Application, which means that your entire site data is loaded on the `/` route. Which means that if you try to access any other page without first loading the site through the `/` route, then it would fail.

Tyler McGinnis has a very good [Blog Post](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/) about the various ways to fix this issue.

Comment: My question is about `http-server` with `react-router`

Comment: Your issue is due to your react bundle not being available on any routes other than on the `/` route. You need to configure your server to serve '/' as a fallback route.

Answer (score 0):

You should use other packages with supporting HTML5 history API like [Servør](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servor) instead of `http-server`.

Comment: Though Servør can definitely be the solution as it falls back to `index.html` by default, and better than `http-server`, but "HTML5 history API" is not the reason here.

Comment: Servør does not support proxying API calls

Answer (score 0):

I think we also need another parameter to run our build app properly.
Here I have used this

```
http-server -P https://localhost:8080/? --proxy-options.secure false -S -C yourpemfile.pem -K yourkeyfile.pem build/
```

Here --proxy-options basically set secure true as a default and for this when run our command it fails to render our build files of our react applications